# Kubernetes injecting secret key as token into a set template file AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, secret-key, aws-secrets-manager

I have a pod and inside it, i need to override a configuration.txt file that contains id and password to database.

For example : when running the application it looks to see if `/etc/configuration.txt` exists , if not it uses a default id and password.

The configuration file is a set template - which is the part that confuses me. How do i insert the ID and password into the config file?. (i am able to set secret inside /etc/configuration.txt but not sure on how to insert 'tokens' or secret values.

configuration.txt

```
id=test
password=test

//rest of the content in side the file to remain the same
```

If someone could tell me if this is the correct practice or if they can share an example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

## With ConfigMap

```sh
kubectl create configmap myconfig --from-file ./configuration.txt
```

update:

```sh
kubectl create configmap myconfig --from-file ./configuration.txt -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl replace -f -
```

// deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
  namespace: YOUR_NAMESPACE
  labels:
    app: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
          image: YOUR_IMAGE_NAME
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/config
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: myconfig
```

```sh
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

path:
/etc/config/configuration.txt

## With secret

convert password

```sh
$ echo -n "testpassword" | base64
dGVzdA==
```

// secrets.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  DB_PASSWORD: dGVzdA==
```

```sh
kubectl apply -f secrets.yaml
```

```sh
kubectl describe secret/mysecret
```

// deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
  namespace: YOUR_NAMESPACE
  labels:
    app: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
          image: YOUR_IMAGE_NAME
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: mysecret
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

```sh
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

with nodejs

```js
const password = process.env.DB_PASSWORD?process.env.DB_PASSWORD:"default_password"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Regarding the secrets part, how is the secret inserted into the configuration.txt file and that mounted onto /etc/config ? And how is the nodejs part used? 

The instructions with config map - i understand it no issues

Comment: Have you read this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/ ?